# Protractor ng-if condition and element availability

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ng-if, evaluate

I want to check whether element displayed or not depends upon ng-if condition,

```
<div id="discount_percent" ng-if="data.isDiscount">  
     <div id="dis_available"> Discount: {{data.discount}} % </div> 
</div>
```

I want to check if `data.isDiscount is true` than `div "discount_percent"` & `dis_available` should display.

> ***Note:*** div "discount_percent" and "dis_available" won't be present in DOM if data.isDiscount is false.

I did following way, but I'm not fully satisfied with my solution.

```
var discountPercentId = element(by.id('discount_percent'));
discountPercentId.isPresent().then(function (present){
   if(present){
      expect(discountPercentId.evaluate("data.isDiscount")).toBeTruthy();
      expect(discountPercentId.element(by.id("dis_available")).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
   }
});
```

Any better approach to do? If condition true than check its availability!!!

Comment: This approach looks reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var elem = element(by.css('[ng-if="data.isDiscount"]'));
elem.isPresent().then(function(fnct){
            if(fnct){
             //do whatever
             }
           else{
            //do something else
             }
        });
```

also, I am not sure, but you might want to get the value of data.IsDiscount first. You can get the value of this with the following function:

```
elem.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) { 
                                    //do something with the value
                                });
```

Comment: elem.getAttribute('value')... would give error if your condition is false. You can only use this inside true condition of isPresent(...) promise.

Comment: Protractor locator should be able to find an ng-if-hidden element. The isPresent() method on its promise should promise to return false. You can also try isDisplayed.